# how to use recursive query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello i have a question related to tree like structure that i try to shown you in table

```
id       name           reportsto
2        Akas           345
3        grity          345
4        kethy          2
5        alex           345
6        holy           3
7        dean           4
8        ambrose        3
9        amily          456
```

now reports to contains parent id like when i am login with reportsto id 345 then the contacts that reports to 345 shown and also contacts that reported to other id that id reported to 345 just like parent child relationship.so finally i want result like 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 but not id 9.so how to achieve that results with mysql query,i have a table that contains many data and its like tree structure.please solve.
i used query but its not deliver exact result

```
select  contactid,firstname,lastname,reportsto from(select * from contactdetails order by reportsto, contactid) contact,(select @pv := '345') initialisation where   find_in_set(reportsto, @pv) > 0 and @pv := concat(@pv, ',', contactid)
```

Comment: Have you seen [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) ?

Comment: yes but i cannot obtain result

Comment: can i do it in php using recursive function

Comment: You should do it in MySQL.  You have two options.  First, you can do it manually by self joining your table some number of times.  Second, you could also use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how to do it using dynamic sql queries,please elaborate